# Using a common class for inheritance and for a member (code-first)

Tags: entity-framework

I've having difficulties getting EF code-first to generate a database from the following entities:

```
public class Person : Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Animal Pet { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So conceptually a person is an animal with a name, and they have a pet that is also an animal with a name. My context contains an array of people but *not* animals, which is why Animal doesn't contain a key:

```
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

If I try to create a database using code-first I get the following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

MyProject.Database.Animal: : EntityType 'Animal' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Animals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Animals' is based on type 'Animal' that has no keys defined.
```

If I remove the `Pet` field I get a table with `Id` and `Name` fields, which is my expected behavior. Similarly, if I remove the `Animal` inheritance I get a table with `Id` and `Pet_Name` fields, which is again my expected behavior. What I'm trying to get is a table with `Id`, `Name` and `Pet_Name` fields.

Can't help but feel I'm missing something very basic here, because I've done this on other ORMs without issue. Can anyone tell me how to do this with EF 6.2?

Comment: Do you need TPH inheritance?

Comment: Try to make `public` **`abstract`** `class Animal`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov yep, already tried that, same result :(

Comment: @MarkFeldman Its seems your concept is wrong! You are going against entity framework design concept. Whenever you are adding `public Animal Pet { get; set; }` to `Person` entity framework treating it as navigation property and expecting a key for this entity to make a foreign in `Person` table.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I would respectfully disagree. The whole point of an Object Relational Mapper is to map relational objects from one OOP hierarchy to another, the model hierarchy should not have to be designed to suit one particular ORM. And as I've already pointed out, other ORMs handle this case with ease. Lacking support for something as fundamental as inheritance would make for a pretty poor ORM IMO, you may as well just do the mapping yourself. I'd be stunned if EF can't handle such a simple case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that reads this in future EF treats classes as either Entities or Complex Types. Entities get their own table while complex types get their own fields added as fields to the classes of parents that contain them as properties. If you declare a class instance as a property of another then EF immediately assumes it's an Entity; if it sees you trying to use it as a base class in an inheritance hierarchy then it assumes it's a complex type. The error shown above occurs when EF has already erroneously assumed that the type is an Entity but you then try to use it as a complex type. Seems to me that EF shouldn't be making the assumption in the first place if the class has no key property, but there it is. The solution is to simply flag it as a complex type from the start in your `OnModelCreating` function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Animal>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```